# No WCF request is sent from Silverlight on client machine

Tags: wcf, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

My SL application is commercial and working just fine on hundreds of machines.

SL is using a WCF service and it works as expected, but today I observed behavior on client machine, where literally no call is made to server.

After you click button that sends a call, some error occures, and no record about WCF call is created in Fiddler.

Error is:

```
[HttpWebRequest_WebException_RemoteServer]
Arguments: NotFound
Debugging resource strings are unavailable...
```

I read about this error that people recommend to use Fiddler, but as I say there is no call displayed in Fiddler

So problem is worse than I thought initially.

It comes and goes. Currently we have found a working solution that fixes the problem after it appears although it doesn't make any sense to me.

> For example if I get this error in chrome & mozilla & OOB version,
>   launching a program in IE works, and after that chrome,mozilla & OOB
>   start to work too.

Thing is that same people who had this problem solved with this workaround experience it again in some days, like a week, with no apparent reason, and then combination of launches from various locations helps (usually IE helps the most).

Any help appreciated, I start a bounty as its pretty sick bug and I need to fix it somehow.

**Update**

Weird IE fix scenario:

At some point OOB version gets into state where it doesn't send any WCF request to server.
(fiddler doesn't see it, server doesn't gets it).
After launching web version in IE, and hitting the same button, that sends WCF request we get desired result in IE web version.

Without changing anything else, just relaunching OOB version which was in this buggest state before, makes OOB version work correctly. Its not reinstalled, not changed - nothing.

This is what I call "IE cure" of this problem.
So the question is what can IE launch potentiall change for OOB version?

Comment: It looks like there may have been an uncaught exception.

Comment: okay I solved problem by some weird manipulations with IE, I went in added my domain in trusted sites, and removed requirement for HTTPS to add to trusted sites, as its not an HTTPS. After that it started to work in IE, but didnt work OOB or in Chrome. I removed it from trusted sites and it started to work everywhere, LOL. What was that?

Comment: in this case it apperas that actual cause of problem going away was IE itself, not trusted zone or anything.

Comment: Do you mix http and https? IE is more likely not to work when mixing http and https, where Chrome and FF will work.

Comment: nope, everything is in HTTP only

Comment: are there any browser extensions or virus scanner installad that probably block the calls

Comment: curious thought. I gotta ask them about it. However I just dont see the logic here, if there is some kind of external program that blocks chrome use AND OOB version use, how can launching it from IE be a cure to its external effect. I am thinking its gotta be something different. but this is a valid potential reason agree..

Comment: Have you tried deleting the IE cache, etc.

I have had instances where a bugfix has been put in place, but it doesn't always get re-downloaded by the browser.  Even on a forced refresh.

I then do the delete cache on that machine, and new code gets downloaded.

Its a bit of a stab in the dark, but I've had that exact same scenario (and others).

Comment: BaconSah, I have added a more detailed description of "IE cure" behaviour. Note that its not related to IE cache I think at all, as it works correctly in IE, problems appear in chrome,mozilla and OOB versions.

Comment: Has the Silverlight app the same origin as the webservice? Cross site and third party cookies have different handling and defaults in different (versions of) browsers.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/lightswitch/thread/56e670f4-9fa2-4a2e-b75a-18524e7cb210/) the message `Debugging resources are unavailable` appears when de client is not using the the Silverlight Developer Runtime.

This means that the actual exception is hidden from you (and us) so the next step is to reproduce the error on a system that has the Silverlight Developer Runtime.

I found [this article](http://www.lditsolutions.com/blog/posts/2013/04/accessing-wcf-services-using-a-self-signed-certificate-from-oob-%28out-of-browser%29-silverlight-or-in-browser-without-getting-any-security-warnings-and-without-storing-a-security-exception). It might be worth it to check the certificate you are using (are you using a certificate) It is one of those things that is different with OOB apps and browsers.

Comment: yep actual message is hidden, thats part of problem. Of course customers don't have developer runtime, and I have seen it only on 3 machines (out of hundreds) But its kinda irrelevant here, by described symptoms I think someone who spent long enough time with Silverlight would be able to recognize whats going on. Any ideas how IE "heals" silverlight are welcome too etc.

Comment: I expect that you are asking too much. I have done a lot of Silverlight development but if you do not have the actual exception and cannot reproduce it, it is extremely hard to pinpoint the problem. It can be anything that makes IE different from any version of any other browser. Start by logging the actual exception in the application (perhaps by writing it to local storage) and trying to replicate the issue.

Comment: I agree that there is a good chance I wont get a solution here, given how I have layed out the problem. If I do however that would be great.

Comment: I added a suggestion on certificates

Comment: curious read for sure, and it does share some attributes of described problem (different behaviours in different browsers/oob). yet I am afraid its not the case, since HTTPS is not used.

Comment: gave bounty, but just in case, this didn't help me get any closer to understand the problem, and it was the only answer

Comment: Thanks :) but you didn't have to give me the bounty if it didn't solve your problem. I am not here for the points. A big thing is that you are not able to reproduce the issue.  it makes it extremely hard to solve.

Comment: not giving bounty makes little sense, otherwise points just vanish, which is even worse.